# Unable to access image from a deployed .net application

Tags: asp.net, image, deployment

I have deployed a .net application on IIS7. But I am facing an issue with accessing the image even in the Login page. I have a master page that is accessing the image with below code -

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img id="imgSpacer" src="logo.jpg" runat="Server" alt="spacer"  /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This image is in the same folder as the master page and works perfectly find in the visual studio.

And help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Try publishing locally (to a directory) and see if the image is where you expect it to be.

Answer (score 1):

Try resolving the path from the root:

```
<img id="imgSpacer" src="~/logo.jpg" runat="Server" alt="spacer" />
```

Comment: Should then I also put the image in parent folder? I am asking this because first I had the image in a different folder and accessed it like src="~/Images/logo.jpg" and still it did not work.

Please note that the problem here is that it works fine in visual studio when I build and run the application but the problem appears only I have deployed.

Comment: Once you resolve the path from the root it will work on both your local machine and the server.